# Camel Blueprint test fails due to error Unable to start bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

My Camel Blueprint test fails with the following exception:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:163)
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:304)
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:248)
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:129)
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:52)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:143)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:108)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:94)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:199)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
                at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
                at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
                at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
                at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
                at org.apache.felix.connect.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:152)
                ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Servlet
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                ... 40 more
Unable to start bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http [11]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)

                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:265)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:226)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createCamelContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:409)
                at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:247)
                at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:217)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:202)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
                at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
                at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
                at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
                at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
                at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
                at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
                at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
                at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

This is the code of the test:

```
import org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport;
import org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker;

public class EnrichMessageWithSourceDataProcessorTest  extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {
@Rule
public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();

@Override
protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
    return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/configuration.xml";
}
@Test
public void processWithNullableExchangeSouldFail(){
// NOP - test fails even if no action has been taken
}
}
```

Here is the Blueprint configuration. See, that no cxf-endpoint is declared, only properties for ActiveMQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
                               http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <cm:property-placeholder id="adpnfmout.placeholder" persistent-id="adpnfmout">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="module" value="AdpNFMOut"/>

            <!-- Public message broker settings -->
            <cm:property name="publicamq.userName" value=""/>
            <cm:property name="publicamq.password" value=""/>
            <cm:property name="publicamq.brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>

        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
    <bean id="publicamq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${publicamq.brokerURL}"/>
        <property name="userName" value="${publicamq.userName}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${publicamq.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="ctxUpdateClientRq" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="route1" startupOrder="20">
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Here is the pom.xml dependency block (we use camel version 2.15.1.redhat-621084 as component of JBossFuse ESB):

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-blueprint</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq-junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is one remarkable circumstance: while starting test produces logs related to CXF:

```
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport (69) [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http (73) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws (74) [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-xml (75) [org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-addr (77) [org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.WSAddressingFeature$WSAddressingFeatureApplier, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MAPAggregator$MAPAggregatorLoader]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy (78) [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine, org.apache.cxf.policy.PolicyDataEngine, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyAnnotationListener, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.DomainExpressionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.EndpointReferenceDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.URIDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMPolicyInterceptorProvider]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap (82) [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory]
[                          main] CXFActivator                   INFO  Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl (83) [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager]
```

and if I remove CXF dependency from pom, then test passes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you fixed it yourself by removing the `camel-cxf` dependency.  But if you actually need it then you need to add a transport implementation to use during tests, e.g.:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but why Blueprint launches components that are NOT in Blueprint configuration file. Actually I don`t need camel-cxf during tests. So I cant understand why does Blueprint decide what to do by looking into my pom?

Comment: Blueprint bundles contain Activators which are detected by the container and invoked when the bundle is started.  The Camel blueprint test framework scans for bundles on the classpath and activates them, so even though you don't reference them they are started.  You can override the `getBundleFilter()` method in your test class to filter out any bundles you have on the classpath that you don't want Camel to activate.  I think!

Comment: Thanks a lot! We have overriden getBundleFilter method like this: return "(Bundle-SymbolicName=org.apache.camel.camel-test)"; but another error came: [main] BrokerService INFO  Apache ActiveMQ 5.11.0.redhat-621084 (embedded-broker, ID:MSK-KARPOV-56638-1545299099704-0:1) is shutdown
java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
                at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:202)